# Integer with different numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

K597M is built with different numbers, like **K != 5, 9, 7, M and M != 5, 9, 7, K**

**K597M/24=k.m+0**

*How many different values of K are there?*

Comment: I assume you mean that $K597M$ is a five-digit number whose first digit is $K$ and whose last is $M$, and all of whose digits are distinct. What does the second line mean? That the number is divisible by 24? Something else?

Comment: @rogerl        Yes, I translate the question from another language. Its divided by 24 and K597M is a five digit number and its digits are distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last digit must be a $6$ because for divisibility by $8$ it is enough to consider the last $3$ digits and the only number of $970$ to $979$, divisible by $8$, is $976$.

The number must be divisible by $3$, a leading zero is not allowed, so the first digit can only be a $3$, otherwise, we would repeat the digit $6$ or $9$. The whole number is $35976$

Comment: Oh I tried it to divide to 6 and 4, that's why I couldn't get to the answer. Thank you.